# PDF Sharp - Cannot edit certain pdfs

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Using the following code, I am able to write page numbers to *SOME* files.

```
  var outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
  var currentPageNumber = 1;

  var inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(@"C:\SamplePdfs\display.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

  for (var i = 0; i < inputDocument.PageCount; i++)
  {
       PdfPage page = outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[i]);
       XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
       XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 100, XFontStyle.Regular);
       gfx.DrawString(Convert.ToString(currentPageNumber), font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width - 100, page.Height - 100), XStringFormats.BottomCenter);
       currentPageNumber++;
  }

  outputDocument.Save(@"c:\test\sample1.pdf");
```

Why would I not be able to use that code to write to certain pdfs?

Update:  I have found a pdf online that exhibits the same issue.
[PDF](http://www.filedropper.com/newdisplay)

Update  #2:  Different host: 
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e0exs0lhytx3xl/ThirdConversion.pdf?dl=0)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e0exs0lhytx3xl/ThirdConversion.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF where your code does not work and more code (an SSCCE would be fine - see http://sscce.org/ ).

Comment: Sorry, no can do.  They contain pii data.  If I could create a sample one, I would know what was causing the issue rendering the question irrelevant.  The code works.  It is something to do with the pdfs themselves.  I will try downloading sample pdfs from the internet and trying to recreate it, but it may be a while before I find one having this problem.

Comment: @ThomasH - I think this is happening because it is a scanned pdf.  If what I am reading is correct, then the whole thing is just a single jpeg inside a pdf wrapper and that is what is stopping me from being able to write to the file.  Does this seem likely?

Comment: The link to the PDF file does not work. The page number should appear above the JPEG image.

Comment: I uploaded an example file to a different host.  Hopefully this one will work.

Answer (score 0):

The file NewDisplay.pdf uses negative values in the MediaBox: `MediaBox[-89.5 -702.5 702.5 -90.5]`

Most PDF files use positive values. Maybe your page numbers will show up when you use negative values for x and y.